# assign value to %s on mocha post function

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js

I am writing tests in mocha and I have a variable which has a string with `%s` in it

```
let api = '/api/Boxer/%s/Role';
```

and I have a variable named `id` which holds the value of `%s` shown above.

```
let id = newUser.id;
```

generally, I pass this api into `post` function of mocha so as to hit a post request, something like this,

```
request(app)
.post(api)
.send(data)
```

My problem is :
I want to pass variable `api` and `id` to post function so that finally it gets resolved to a single string.

Please help me to achieve this, or If I am wrong then what should be the correct way to form a single string which could be passed to `post` function.

Comment: You can do `let new_api = api.replace("%s",id);`.  Then do, 
`request(app)
.post(new_api)
.send(data)`

Comment: @vivek_23 what if there are more than 1 %s  in my string ?

Comment: Interesting. Will you have only `%s` as your placeholders or it could be `%d` or something else as well?

Comment: there are very less chances of having any other placeholders but still it may be possible to have them as well

Comment: I have added my answer and currently works for `%s`. You can also make it work for `%d` by passing `%d` as `placeholder` in parameters. I hope you don;t consider these as format specifiers as this will involve type checking as well. Regardless, when you send data in post, it is going to be a string ultimately

Answer (score 1):

This function below checks for all `%s` placeholders and replaces them with their respective values.

```js
function replacePlaceHolders(str, placeholder, new_values) {

  var new_str = "";
  var pl_len = placeholder.length;
  var ptr = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - pl_len; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < pl_len; ++j) {
      if (str[i + j] != placeholder[j]) {
        new_str += str[i];
        break;
      } else if (j == pl_len - 1) {
        if (ptr === new_values.length) throw "Insufficient placeholder values given for " + str;
        new_str += new_values[ptr++];
        i = i + pl_len - 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return new_str;
}

try {
  console.log(replacePlaceHolders('/api/Boxer/%s/Role', '%s', ['87']));
  console.log(replacePlaceHolders('/api/Boxer/%s%s/Role', '%s', ['87', 94]));
  console.log(replacePlaceHolders('%s/api/Boxer/%s/%s/Role/%s', '%s', ['some_text', '87', 94, 'javascript']));
  console.log(replacePlaceHolders('%s%s%s%s', '%s', ['some_text', '87', 94, 'javascript']));
  console.log(replacePlaceHolders('%s%s%s%s', '%s', ['some_text', '87', 94]));

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```